# dpms keeps turning itself off periodically

Tags: debian, dpms, xset

original problem: on waking from screensaver/standby (not sure which), Xorg squishes dual monitors into a single screen, which I can't seem to undo without `service xdm restart` (I know of on way to extract an xrandr command from xorg.conf)

- solution: `xset +dpms` prevents this 'bug', for some reason

second problem: `xset +dpms` doesn't work in `.xsession`

- solution: I set it with a `sleep` beforehand, so after initializing the xsession, `xset q` properly says "`DPMS enabled`"

**actual problem (this question)**: periodically (seemingly randomly), DPMS unsets itself, and `xset q` after a screensaver/standby will result in `DPMS disabled` even though I haven't done `xset -dpms` anywhere

what program is setting DPMS off, and/or is it a bug which will obligate me to run a script that sets `xset +dpms` every 4 minutes as long as the computer is on................................. how could I maybe debug this besides writing a script to let me know when DPMS switches to Disabled, such as finding the specific process that fiddles with the xset config

(would setting this in xorg.conf fix things?)

thank you

Comment: the current workaround I have is to do `xrandr --setmonitor left `2560/25x1600/20+-1000+0` or something (numbers incorrect), which seems to reactivate the missing monitor, even though the geometry parameter is incorrect (it says it performed an "add monitor")